# How to sync the table of postgresql schema - Sequelize ORM

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two schemas in my postgres

1. public // default schema
2. first_user

Now I have same tables in both schemas

I changed the table structure, so I want to run the sync now,
I sync the tables using:

```
const db = new Sequelize(postgres_db, postgres_user, postgres_pwd, {
  host: postgres_host,
  port: 5432,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
});

db.sync().then(() => {
  console.log('Table Synced');
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

After running this my table structure inside the public schema changed successfully, but my first_user schema's table structure remains same.

How to solve this?

NOTE: I don't want to lose my data inside my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally implemented this using sequelize migrations

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Sequelize migration because of lack of Typescript support you can fall back to Migra which is easy to use.
https://djrobstep.com/docs/migra

Answer (score -1):

You Can Try **CREATE TABLE AS TABLE** Query.

```js
create table first_user.tableName as table public.tableName;
```

It will create the  table with updated table structure as well as with the data.

Thanks..